# Integrate a tree in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a query like below:

```
 select * from (
select * from (
select distinct * from TBL_IDPS_TREE 
START WITH LEDGER_CODE in  (

 10912520000
,10825060000
,10912380000
,11311110201
)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR  parent_CODE = LEDGER_CODE
  )a  left join (
select /*+ PARALLEL(AUTO) */  balance as "y300" , ledger_code as "id",'' as "x300" , round(abs(balance)/30835,2) as "z300",name as "name"   from tbl_ledger_archive where ledger_code in ( 
10912520000
,10825060000
,10912380000
,11311110201) and eff_date ='29-MAY-19'
) b
on a.LEDGER_CODE = b."id")
START WITH PARENT_CODE is null
connect by PRIOR LEDGER_CODE = Parent_CODE

 ;
```

and the result is : 
[image]

x300,y300,z300 are the value of tree.

I want to change a query that integrate the tree value for x300,y300,z300
I mean the query must integrate tree value from leaves to root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `connect_by_root` in the account tree subquery and join with ledger by it.

Demo:

```
with TBL_IDPS_TREE as (
  select 10912520000 LEDGER_CODE, 1091252 parent_CODE from dual union all
  select 10825060000, 1091252 from dual union all
  select 1091252, 1091 from dual union all
  select 1091, null from dual
), tbl_ledger_archive as (
   select  500000 as "y300" , 10912520000 as "id", '' as "x300" , round(500000/30835, 2) as "z300", 'abc' as "name" from dual union all
   select  600000 as "y300" , 10825060000 as "id", '' as "x300" , round(600000/30835, 2) as "z300", 'abc' as "name" from dual 
)
select a.LEDGER_CODE, a.parent_CODE, l."x300", sum(l."y300") "y300", sum(l."z300") "z300"
from (
  select distinct t.*, connect_by_root LEDGER_CODE as accRoot
  from TBL_IDPS_TREE t
     START WITH LEDGER_CODE in  (
                 10912520000 
        ,10825060000
        ,10912380000
        ,11311110201
        )
      CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_CODE = LEDGER_CODE
) a
left join tbl_ledger_archive l
  on l."id" = a.accRoot 
group by a.LEDGER_CODE, a.parent_CODE, l."x300" ;
```